# Django- ValueError [The User couldn't be created because the data didn't validate]

Tags: python, django

I used extend user model based on [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone) tutorial.When I submit the registration form this error occurs.This errors shows for both time I use is_active() and is_active in my code.
How to resolve this error?
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnGzs.png<br)
[registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl9H6.png<br)
[new error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XINj6.png)
Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    codeforces_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    Uva_Id = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    #receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    #receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import UserForm,ProfileForm

class UserFormView(View):
    user_form_class = UserForm
    profile_form_class= ProfileForm
    #display a blank form
    def get(self , request):
         user_form = self.user_form_class(None)
         profile_form = self.profile_form_class(None)
         return render(request, 'website/registration_form.html',{
            'user_form':user_form,
            'profile_form':profile_form
            })
    #process form data
    def post(self, request):
        user_form = self.user_form_class(request.POST)
        profile_form = self.profile_form_class(request.POST)
        user= user_form.save(commit=  False)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            password= user_form.cleaned_data['password']
            username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            user.set_password(password)

            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()

            # auto login 
            user = authenticate(username =username, password = password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active():
                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect('website:index')
        return render(request, 'website/registration_form.html',{
            'user_form':user_form,
            'profile_form':profile_form
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You saved the form before validate.
Add `user = user_form.save(commit=  False)` into your if statement

```
def post(self, request):
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user= user_form.save(commit=  False)
            password= user_form.cleaned_data['password']
            username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            user.set_password(password)

            user.save() # You can update user object like this
            profile_form.save()

            # auto login 
            user = authenticate(username =username, password = password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active():
                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect('website:index')
        return render(request, 'website/registration_form.html',{
            'user_form':user_form,
            'profile_form':profile_form
            })
```

The second error caused because when call `user.save()` it automatically executes the signal defined in your model. But you commented `@receiver(post_save, sender=User)`.  It is crucial and uncomment it.

Comment: Thanks. but now it is showing another error. IntegrityError "NOT NULL constraint failed: website_profile.user_id". Did I miss something ?

Comment: Did you do everything specified in the tutorial? Can you post your model

Comment: Please, check it again.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Don't neglect any decorators. Its important pieces of code.

Comment: #receiver(post_save, sender=User) did you see this in your model.py?

Comment: Its actually @receiver(post_save, sender=User)

Comment: Add user instance in form while saving. Aswer updated